# How can I delete duplicates documents across multiple fields in Mongodb or Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, duplicates, pymongo, findall

I have billions of data including Geometry field in a collection, like this:
Doc1:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61ea9daff9a37e64d24099c2"
    },
    "mobile_ad_id": "6122d81b-750b-4cf4-9dc0-d779294f514a",
    "Date": "2021-11-19",
    "Time": "19:50:55",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [72.910606, 19.09972]
    },
    "ipv_4": "103.251.50.0",
    "publisher": "1077c92082522992f0adcd46b31a51eb"
}
```

Doc2:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61ea9daff9a37e64d24099c3"
        },
        "mobile_ad_id": "6122d81b-750b-4cf4-9dc0-d779294f514a",
        "Date": "2021-11-19",
        "Time": "19:50:55",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [72.910606, 19.09972]
        },
        "ipv_4": "103.251.51.0",
        "publisher": "1077c92082522992f0adcd46b31a53eb"
    }
```

I need to find and delete the duplicate documents based on **"mobile_ad_id", "Date", "Time", and "geometry"**.

So Instead of two docs I'll have only one documents.

I need to run this for billions of entries in the collection, so an optimized solution would be ideal.

Comment: When you find duplicates, you want to keep one of them, yes?  Which one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out duplicate documents by using `$group`.
2. `$slice` the id_List and keep those id that you actually want to remove.
3. Using `$limit` to get part of data per aggregate.
4. Try to `$remove` part of data from previous action. Also make sure that those data are being removed correctly.
5. You can make the `$limit` of number bigger once you know how long those action will take. And the time spent is acceptable to you.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        mobile_ad_id: "$mobile_ad_id",
        Date: "$Date",
        Time: "$Time",
        geometry: "$geometry"
      },
      id_List: { $push: "$_id" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      id_List: { $slice: [ "$id_List", { $subtract: [ { $size: "$id_List" }, 1 ] } ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1000
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/abODoeChEJD)

---

```
db.collection.remove( { _id: { $in: id_List } } )
```

I think you are working on IOT devices. Maybe you don't need to remove duplicates. You can share with me if there is some `query` bothering you. And those performance is bad due to duplicates documents.